# Transposing an sql result so that one column goes onto multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I'm trying to get data out of a table for a survey in a particular format. However all my attempts seems to hand the DB because of too many joins/too heavy on the DB.

My data looks like this:

```
id, user, question_id, answer_id, 
1,   1,   1,           1
3,   1,   3,           15
4,   2,   1,           2
5,   2,   2,           12
6,   2,   3,           20
```

There are roughly 250,000 rows and each user has about 30 rows. I want the result to look like:

```
user0, q1, q2,   q3 
1,     1,  NULL, 15
2,     2,  12,   20
```

So that each user has one row in the result, each with a separate column for each answer.

I'm using Postgres but answers in any SQL language would be appreciated as I could translate to Postgres.

EDIT: I also need to be able to deal with users not answering questions, i.e. in the example above q2 for user 1.

Comment: search a crosstab keyword here 

for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following demo:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE qa (id int, usr int, question_id int, answer_id int);
INSERT INTO qa VALUES
 (1,1,1,1)
,(2,1,2,9)
,(3,1,3,15)
,(4,2,1,2)
,(5,2,2,12)
,(6,2,3,20);

SELECT *
FROM   crosstab('
    SELECT usr::text
          ,question_id
          ,answer_id
    FROM qa
    ORDER BY 1,2')
 AS ct (
     usr text
    ,q1 int
    ,q2 int
    ,q3 int);
```

Result:

```
 usr | q1 | q2 | q3
-----+----+----+----
 1   |  1 |  9 | 15
 2   |  2 | 12 | 20
(2 rows)
```

`user` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Don't use it as column name! I renamed it to `usr`.

You need to install the additional module [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) which provides the function `crosstab()`. Note that this operation is strictly *per database*.
In PostgreSQL **9.1** you can simply:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

For older version you would execute a shell-script supplied in your `contrib` directory. In Debian, for PostgreSQL **8.4**, that would be:

```
psql mydb -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/tablefunc.sql
```

Comment: This is where I went initially, but I'm struggling to cope with missing data, edited question. So if a user doesn't have a row for question 2, it should still output a null (or 0). Have an upvote for effort anyway :)

Comment: Crosstab syntax can be a bit challenging...you'll need a row returned for each answer for each user in order for it to populate correctly.  Inside the quoted area in the cross tab report, build a table (subquery can handle it..something like from user inner join questions on 1=1.  Remember the order by!).  Then left join this back to your data to populate the values.  Otherwise missing answers for a user will offset the fields incorrectly.

Comment: @Twelfth: There is the variant with two parameters [`crosstab(text, text)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html#AEN138286) that takes care of missing categories by providing an explicit list of the categories in the second parameter. More details in [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074489/postgres-buckets-always-filled-from-left-in-crosstab-query/11075727#11075727).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter:  Thanks, that actually simplifies this a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Erwins answer is good, until missing answer for a user shows up.   I'm going to make an assumption on you....you have a users table that has one row per user and you have a questions table that has one row per questions.

```
select usr, question_id
from users u inner join questions q on 1=1
order by 1,
```

This statement will create a row for every user/question, and be in the same order.  Turn it into a subquery and left join it to your data...

```
select usr,question_id,qa.answer_id
from
(select usr, question_id
from users u inner join questions q on 1=1
)a
left join qa on qa.usr = a.usr and qa.question_id = a.usr
order by 1,2
```

Plug that into Erwins crosstab statement and give him credit for the answer :P

Comment: Just to add...you will need to define the crosstab results for each field returned.  If you have 3 answers, AS ct (
     usr text
    ,q1 int
    ,q2 int
    ,q3 int); works.  If you have 30, be prepared to define each one like this.  If you have a new question added, the crosstab select statement will pick it up, but you will need to ensure you add the field to this ct() list

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a truly dynamic function to handle this problem without having to hard code any specific number of questions or use external modules/extensions. It also much simpler to use than `crosstab()`.

You can find it here: https://github.com/jumpstarter-io/colpivot

Example that solves this particular problem:

```
begin;

create temp table qa (id int, usr int, question_id int, answer_id int);
insert into qa values
 (1,1,1,1)
,(2,1,2,9)
,(3,1,3,15)
,(4,2,1,2)
,(5,2,2,12)
,(6,2,3,20);

select colpivot('_output', $$
    select usr, ('q' || question_id::text) question_id, answer_id from qa
$$, array['usr'], array['question_id'], '#.answer_id', null);

select * from _output;

rollback;
```

Result:

```
 usr | 'q1' | 'q2' | 'q3' 
-----+------+------+------
   1 |    1 |    9 |   15
   2 |    2 |   12 |   20
(2 rows)
```