# Crosstab function for PostgreSQL 8.0.1

Tags: database, function, postgresql, stored-procedures, crosstab

I want to create a crosstab function for the [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database version 8.0.1. Because it was implemented after PostgreSQL 8.4.0, I am not table to take advantage of the same function.
Is there a way for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8833679/939860

Comment: I actually think [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854460/939860) should work for 8.0 with the custom aggregate at the end of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL 8.0.1?!?

PostgreSQL 8.0.x is unsupported, but if you're still running 8.0.1 you don't mind about that because you haven't applied any patches. You are running a release with *multiple known data loss bugs*. You need to upgrade to - at minimum - the latest 8.0.x release, then start planning your move to 9.0 or 9.1 fairly urgently.

That'll solve your current problem as a handy side-effect.