# PostgreSQL row to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, row, crosstab

I'm trying to create a dynamic system that allows the users to import lists of data from Excel so I need to have dynamic columns, ex:

```
custom_columns_table
id   list_id  data_type       column_name  data              ....
1    1        VARCHAR(255)    email        jhon@example.com  ....
2    1        VARCHAR(255)    name         Jhon              ....

list_table
id
1
```

I need a result like this:

```
id email             name  ....
1  jhon@example.com  Jhon  ....
```

I have found some examples using crosstab but I don`t know if it will work in this case.

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

First off, the `crosstab()` family of functions is not installed in standard PostgreSQL. You need to install the extension [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) for this. In PostgreSQL 9.1 you would simply:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

For older versions have a look at this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8492477/939860).

#### Query

The query *could* look like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab (
       'SELECT l.id
             , c.column_name
             , c.data
        FROM   custom_columns_table c
        JOIN   list_table l ON l.id = c.list_id
        ORDER  BY 1',

       'SELECT DISTINCT column_name
        FROM   custom_columns_table
        ORDER  BY 1'  --?
       ) AS tbl (id integer, email text, name text);
```

I use the form of `crosstab()` with two parameters, because that allows for missing attributes. Like, when a person has no email. Then this form will return `NULL` for the `email` column. See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

**But** the column definition list must be in sync with the second parameter anyway. So it only makes limited sense to make one dynamic and the other one static. It's only justified to catch varying `column_name` - that still sort to fit the same output column definition list.

#### Function

Or create a function so you don't have to supply a column definition list for every call:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_mycross(text, text)
  RETURNS TABLE (id integer, email text, name text)
  LANGUAGE c STABLE STRICT AS
  '$libdir/tablefunc','crosstab_hash';
```

Call:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   f_mycross(
       'SELECT l.id
             , c.column_name
             , c.data
        FROM   custom_columns_table c
        JOIN   list_table l ON l.id = c.list_id
        ORDER  BY 1'
    
       'SELECT DISTINCT column_name
        FROM   custom_columns_table
        ORDER  BY 1');
```