# Dynamic Crosstab in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have this database called e-classroom with tables :

**tbl_enrollment**
[image: tbl_enrollment]

**tbl_feenames**

[image: tbl_feenames]

**tbl_feetypes**

[image: tbl_feetypes]

**tbl_payments**

[image: tbl_payments]

**tbl_pupil**
[image: tbl_pupil]

this is the view that I made out from those tables :

**view_paylist**
[image: view_paylist]

and I have this MySQL query that will pivot these tables :

```
 SET @sql = NULL;
 SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
 CONCAT('MAX(IF(vp.cfeename = ''',vp.cfeename,
        ''', vp.nfeetypeamount, NULL)) AS ',
 CONCAT("`",vp.cfeename,"`")
    )
  ) INTO @sql
 FROM view_paylist AS vp;

 SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT vp.clrn
                , vp.name
                , vp.cgrdlvl
                , csection
                , vp.csy, ', @sql, ' 
               FROM view_paylist vp
 where vp.cgrdlvl like ''%''
 group by vp.clrn
                ');

 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

and this is the result of the pivot :

[image: pivot]

the field "sample" is my newly added data to tbl_feenames. What I want is how can I achieve this dynamic pivoting in PostgreSQL using Crosstab ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Comment: No, that's not dynamic crosstab

Comment: This is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879672/dynamically-generate-columns-for-crosstab-in-postgresql