# PostgreSql pivot table from two tables - performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, pivot-table, crosstab

I have question about performance:

I have table `Employees`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name surname 1 |
| 2 | name surname 2 |

And table `plan`

| emp_id | shift_date | shift_begin | shift_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 08:00 | 17:00 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 08:00 | 17:00 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | 08:00 | 17:00 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 08:00 | 17:00 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 08:00 | 17:00 |
| 2 | 2022-01-03 | 08:00 | 17:00 |

Note: emp_id is a id of employee

and I have following query:

```
SELECT id,name,
(select concat_ws('-',to_char(shift_begin ,'HH24:MI'),to_char(shift_end ,'HH24:MI'),typ) from plan where plan.emp_id = employee.id and shift_date =  '2022-01-01') as d0,
(select concat_ws('-',to_char(shift_begin ,'HH24:MI'),to_char(shift_end ,'HH24:MI'),typ) from plan where plan.emp_id = employee.id and shift_date = '2022-01-02') as d1,
(select concat_ws('-',to_char(shift_begin ,'HH24:MI'),to_char(shift_end ,'HH24:MI'),typ) from plan where plan.emp_id = employee.id and shift_date = '2022-01-03') as d2,
(select concat_ws('-',to_char(shift_begin ,'HH24:MI'),to_char(shift_end ,'HH24:MI'),typ) from plan where plan.emp_id = employee.id and shift_date = '2022-01-04') as d3,
(select concat_ws('-',to_char(shift_begin ,'HH24:MI'),to_char(shift_end ,'HH24:MI'),typ) from plan where plan.emp_id = employee.id and shift_date = '2022-01-05') as d4
-- continues to end of month
from employee;
```

Result is pretty good...

| id | name | d0 | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | ---> d30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name surname 1 | 08:00-17:00 | 08:00-17:00 |  | 08:00-17:00 |  | ---> d30 |
| 2 | name surname 2 | 08:00-17:00 | 08:00-17:00 | 08:00-17:00 |  |  | ---> d30 |

...but when I have for example 50 employees which I would display in table (50 emp * 31 days) it drops in performance (after insert, delete)...

I have a crosstab too but it doesn't show me any results

Now back to the topic: Its a good option ? or use crosstab ? (Fyi in crosstab I have selection from table plan, but I want to select each of table employee).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Select *once* from the table use use a *case expression*

Comment: do you mean contidional aggregation ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, *conditional* using a case expression.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to pivot that works in most databases is conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT emp.id, emp.name
, STRING_AGG(CASE EXTRACT(DAY FROM plan.shift_date) WHEN 1 THEN concat_ws('-',to_char(plan.shift_begin,'HH24:MI'),to_char(plan.shift_end,'HH24:MI'),typ) END, ';') AS d1
, STRING_AGG(CASE EXTRACT(DAY FROM plan.shift_date) WHEN 2 THEN concat_ws('-',to_char(plan.shift_begin,'HH24:MI'),to_char(plan.shift_end,'HH24:MI'),typ) END, ';') AS d2
, STRING_AGG(CASE EXTRACT(DAY FROM plan.shift_date) WHEN 3 THEN concat_ws('-',to_char(plan.shift_begin,'HH24:MI'),to_char(plan.shift_end,'HH24:MI'),typ) END, ';') AS d3
-- continues to end of month
FROM employee emp
LEFT JOIN plan 
  ON plan.emp_id = emp.id
 AND plan.shift_date >= '2022-01-01' 
 AND plan.shift_date  < '2022-02-01' 
GROUP BY emp.id, emp.name
ORDER BY emp.id, emp.name;
```

If it's certain that they only have 1 shift per day.
Then `MAX` will do just fine.

```
, MAX(CASE EXTRACT(DAY FROM plan.shift_date) WHEN 31 THEN concat_ws('-',to_char(plan.shift_begin,'HH24:MI'),to_char(plan.shift_end,'HH24:MI'),typ) ELSE '' END) AS d31
```

Comment: but "shift_date" is from another table how to achieve this?

Comment: Had to add the join to plan

Comment: Problem solved for now thanks for help.

Comment: Check update, by comparing the day of the month it'll be easy to change month by changing the `WHERE` criteria.

Comment: Okay thanks i look on this, but there is little problem, if some month have a 28 days like february or 30 ?

Comment: Currently d31 would be NULL then.  Unless you put an `ELSE '' ` in the `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Perfect, thanks...

Comment: Btw, I changed MAX to STRING_AGG. Just in case some have more than 1 shift per day.

Comment: It is treated to always 1 shift for each employee  / 1 day, currently i have used cond. aggregation MAX() with case then else and its work fast.

Answer (score 0):

For lots of result columns, `crosstab()` is typically shortest and fastest:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT p.emp_id, e.name, p.shift_date
        , concat_ws('-', to_char(p.shift_begin, 'HH24:MI'), to_char(p.shift_end,'HH24:MI'))
   FROM   employees e
   LEFT   JOIN plan p ON p.emp_id = e.id
                     AND p.shift_date >= '2022-01-01' 
                     AND p.shift_date <= '2022-01-31' 
   ORDER  BY e.id, p.shift_date;
   $$
 , $$SELECT generate_series (timestamp '2022-01-01'
                           , timestamp '2022-01-31'
                           , interval '1 day')::date$$
   ) AS ct (
      id int, name text
    , d1  text, d2  text, d3  text, d4  text, d5  text, d6  text, d7  text, d8  text, d9  text, d10 text
    , d11 text, d12 text, d13 text, d14 text, d15 text, d16 text, d17 text, d18 text, d19 text, d20 text
    , d21 text, d22 text, d23 text, d24 text, d25 text, d26 text, d27 text, d28 text, d29 text, d30 text
    , d31 text);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ab9f253ffd72b351d4b29618404653ae)*

See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Why  `generate_series (timestamp '2022-01-01', ...`? See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

I would generate above query dynamically for any given date range. Related examples:

- [Get rows for the last 10 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905410/get-rows-for-the-last-10-dates/32912360#32912360)
- [PostgreSQL convert columns to rows? Transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084503/postgresql-convert-columns-to-rows-transpose/14087244#14087244)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to aggregate the shift per employee before doing the "pivot", e.g. into a JSON value:

```
SELECT emp.id, 
       emp.name,
       shifts ->> '1' as d1,
       shifts ->> '2' as d2,
       shifts ->> '3' as d3,
       shifts ->> '4' as d4,
       shifts ->> '5' as d5,
       shifts ->> '6' as d6,
       shifts ->> '7' as d7,
       shifts ->> '8' as d8,
       shifts ->> '9' as d9,
       ... 
from employees emp
  left join (
    select emp_id, 
           jsonb_object_agg(extract(day from shift_date),
                            concat_ws('-', to_char(shift_begin, 'hh24:mi'), to_char(shift_end, 'hh24:mi'))) as shifts
    from plan p
     where p.shift_date >= '2022-01-01' 
       and p.shift_date  < '2022-02-01' 
    group by emp_id
  ) p on p.emp_id = emp.id
order by emp.id;
;
```

Depending on how you use the result, you might not even need to extract each day into a separate column if you can use the JSON value directly in your frontend.