# Unique Rows to Columns in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot, unpivot

I have table of data that is sorted as follows:

```
Item    |   Sample  |   Value   |
---------------------------------
Part A  |   Top     |   1.0     |
Part A  |   Bottom  |   4.0     |
Part A  |   Left    |   3.0     |
Part A  |   Right   |   2.0     |
Part A  |   Center  |   5.0     |
Part B  |   Top     |   6.0     |
Part B  |   Bottom  |   1.0     |
Part B  |   Left    |   1.0     |
Part B  |   Right   |   5.0     |
Part B  |   Center  |   9.0     |
Part C  |   Top     |   7.0     |
Part C  |   Bottom  |   5.0     |
Part C  |   Left    |   1.0     |
Part C  |   Right   |   2.0     |
Part C  |   Center  |   1.0     |
```

That I'm trying to perform further statistical analysis on.  For those calculations, it would be ideal for the data to be outputted like this:

```
Item    |   Top     |   Bottom  |   Left    |   Right   |   Center  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Part A  |   1.0     |   4.0     |   3.0     |   2.0     |   5.0     |
Part B  |   3.0     |   1.0     |   1.0     |   5.0     |   9.0     |
Part C  |   7.0     |   5.0     |   1.0     |   2.0     |   1.0     |
```

I believe in MSSQL you can use the PIVOT or UNPIVOT functions to accomplish this, but I'm unsure in Postgresql.  All the similar solutions I found seemed vague.  Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `crosstab()` function of the [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) extension for that.

I have posted multiple examples with links and detailed explanation on SO recently. [Try a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D%20user:939860%20crosstab&submit=search).

Comment: Thanks Erwin, didn't find your articles when I was looking.  For anyone else, here is an almost identical example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490478/transposing-an-sql-result-so-that-one-column-goes-onto-multiple-columns/8492477#8492477