# using cross tab and pivot table function

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, crosstab

Possibility of using cross tab and pivot table function in postgres 8.3 version

I know it is possible with postgres 9.x version, but wanted to know by any chance we can use it with the older versions of postgres.

I am using hibernate for the database connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the additional module [`tablefunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/tablefunc.html) providing several variants of the `crosstab()` function is available for PostgreSQL 8.3.

More Info on how to install additional modules [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490478/transposing-an-sql-result-so-that-one-column-goes-onto-multiple-columns/8492477#8492477).
Also, check out the tag [crosstab](/questions/tagged/crosstab), combine it with [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), you'll find a number of [examples under related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crosstab+postgresql).