# How to transpose columns and rows in PostgreSQL (i.e., how do I switch rows and columns)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transposing an sql result so that one column goes onto multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490478/transposing-an-sql-result-so-that-one-column-goes-onto-multiple-columns)

I'd like to do a sort of row/column swapping in my PSQL database. Here's my example database:

```
id  place   price   year
1   U.S.    80  2000
2   U.S.    60  2001
3   U.S.    40  2002    
4   U.K.    600 2000
5   U.K.    500 2001
6   U.K.    350 2002
```

I would like to transform that table into the following example:

```
year    U.S.    U.K.
2000    80  600
2001    60  500
2002    40  350
```

Is this possible in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You'll find lots of results, not necessarily postgres-related, if you search for the term [tag:pivot]. Note that Oracle and SQL Server actually implement a `PIVOT` clause, but not Postgres

Comment: Check out the crosstab functions in the tablefunc module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: See: https://github.com/jumpstarter-io/colpivot for a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this easily with an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement:

```
select year,
  sum(case when place = 'U.S.' then price else 0 end) "U.S.",
  sum(case when place = 'U.K.' then price else 0 end) "U.K."
from yourtable
group by year
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2066f/2)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a "pivot", and there's no special syntax in postgres to support it - you have to code it using SQL, for example:

```
select
    year,
    us.price as us,
    uk.price as uk
from mytable us
left join mytable uk on us.year = uk.year
```

Comment: do that with 100 columns and you're doomed … see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29